# Is there a way to increase wall thickness after applying solidify?

Tags: modeling

I'm going to go ahead and do it manually, but before I do I would like to know if there is a better way

Comment: Did you try the thickness setting on the modifier?

Comment: Delete inside faces and either redo the solidify modifier, or use the solidify edit mode operator?

Comment: If the mesh isn't that complex it may work using scaling along normals (`Alt`+`S`) with Even thickness turned on of faces created by modifier

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in edit mode you might prefer if you select the wall faces and press Ctrl F and choose Solidify. The thickness appears in the operator on the left. The new faces are automatically highlighted so at that point, you can add the new faces to a new group. Then if you make further modifications and want the thickness different you can select the faces from the group, delete and redo.